# Don't starve Lua: Can't figure out how to spawn additional bamboo with each bamboo tree, or other machete resources

Tags: lua

I'm building, or trying to build, a mod called More Drops (DS). I ported it to Don't Starve from "Don't Starve Together", so my lua knowledge is very limited, but I've been working on this thing for days and can't figure it out, so I need to ask for help.

I figured out how to expand on the original mod authors work by adding new trees and resources, but when it comes to "hackable" resources, I'm stumped.

---

So this is what I was trying, and tons of variations on this. This doesn't work and I don't understand why, and I'll show you what does work in the next two.

```
--bamboo
if inst.name == "Bamboo Patch" and utils.LootRandom(bambooChance) then 
utils.DoTimes(GetModConfigData("bambooAmount", KnownModIndex:GetModActualName("(JEM) More Drops DS")), inst.components.lootdropper.SpawnLootPrefab, inst.components.lootdropper, "bamboo")  
end
```

This does work

```
--Spawn extra logs for tall trees
if inst.components.growable.stage == 3 and utils.LootRandom(logChance) then
utils.DoTimes(GetModConfigData("extralogstall", KnownModIndex:GetModActualName("(JEM) More Drops DS")), inst.components.lootdropper.SpawnLootPrefab, inst.components.lootdropper, "log")
end
```

And this works as well

```
if inst.name == "Evergreen" and inst.components.growable.stage ~= 1 then
if utils.DropLootRandom(inst, "pinecone", seed_chance) then print("Dropped seed") end
end
```

Now I'm not sure how much of the files I should paste here, but here's the start of the trees.lua just to add a bit more context

```
local utils = require("utils")

local logChance = GetModConfigData("logChance", KnownModIndex:GetModActualName("(JEM) More Drops DS"))

local function ImproveTree(inst)
--Do these when the tree is fully chopped
 local seed_chance  = GetModConfigData("treeseedchance", KnownModIndex:GetModActualName("(JEM) More Drops DS"))
 local egg_chance = GetModConfigData("eggChance", KnownModIndex:GetModActualName("(JEM) More Drops DS"))
 local coconut_seed_chance = GetModConfigData("coconutChance", KnownModIndex:GetModActualName("(JEM) More Drops DS"))
 local bambooChance = GetModConfigData("bambooChance", KnownModIndex:GetModActualName("(JEM) More Drops DS"))

local oldonfinish = inst.components.workable.onfinish
inst.components.workable:SetOnFinishCallback(function(inst, chopper)
```

All of the info is called in modmain.lua correctly as far as I can tell, I made sure to add things in the same way as the working code.

---

I expected this to drop some extra bamboo! I've tried so many different ways, even made my own choppable.lua file and added it the same way the original author added pickable.lua, but I figured it's gotta be a bit more like trees than regular resources, since you use a tool and it drops the item on the ground rather than adding to invetory.

If you want to see the whole mod, I've uploaded it here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/ahss2d0s861j2an/%28JEM%29%20More%20Drops%20DS.7z?dl=0

Comment: This questions seems really based on how the underlying API works. You'll probably get better help in a "Don't Starve" specific forum.

Comment: I'll try that thanks